# CSS Animation not working on Firefox the first time it loads

Tags: css, firefox

I have a small div without text and when I hover over it, the text appears. When it appears I want a zoom animation to happen. The code I have is working fine on Chrome and Edge but on Firefox the zoom animation is not working, the first time the page loads.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        @keyframes animatezoom{
            0%{transform:scale(0);}
            100%{transform:scale(1);}
        }
        .divClass{
            background: lightblue;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
        }
        .textClass{
            display:none;
            animation:animatezoom 0.6s;
        }
        .divClass:hover .textClass{
            display:inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="divClass">
        <p class="textClass">Text</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using Firefox Quantum 58.0.1

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qkybnnjh/). (Make sure to click Run/Refresh after doing hover since the lack of animation only happens the first time the code runs)

Comment: Works fine here both in FF 52 ESR and FF 60 Nightly. (The text "Text" appears on hover without having to do a Run or refresh explicitly.)

Comment: But does it do the animation the first it loads?

Comment: Yes, it animates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set animation on hover:

```
    .textClass {
      display: none;
    }

    .divClass:hover .textClass {
      animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```